# ToString() error with C# expression via Azure API Management

Tags: azure, azure-api-management

I got errors below trying to converting a type to string, like below:

```
  <set-variable name="a" value="@(context.Variables["a"].ToString())" />
Error in element 'set-variable' on line 16, column 10: Usage of member 'ToString' of type 'System.Object' is not supported within expressions


 <set-variable name="a" value="@(context.Variables["a"])" />
    Error in element 'set-variable' on line 16, column 10: Expression return type 'System.Object' is not allowed
```

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/api-management/api-management-policy-expressions

Answer (score 6, accepted):

.ToString() will not work.

Use this expression instead:

```
@(context.Variables.GetValueOrDefault<string>("a"))
```

or if you want to have and empty default string in case the variable is not existing or null:

```
@(context.Variables.GetValueOrDefault<string>("a",""))
```

Answer (score 0):

You can try casting like below:

```
@((string)context.Variables["a"]))
```